# Google Cloud Storage Get Metadata Information of Clicked Image

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-storage, metadata

I have a Node.js backend React frontend application. In my React application, I listed several images taken from the Google Cloud Storage and when an image is clicked, a popup page will be opened and in the popup page, I want to display the clicked image with larger scale, metadata information and location information (taken from ip).

I can obtain metadata information for any image (one image). The code for obtaining metadata information for one image:

```
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
// Imports the Google Cloud client library
const { Storage } = require("@google-cloud/storage");

const bucketName = "myBucket";
const filename = "detected/0.jpg";

const storage = new Storage();

const app = express();

app.get("/api/metadata", cors(), async (req, res, next) => {
  try {

    // Gets the metadata for the file
    const [metadata] = await storage
      .bucket(bucketName)
      .file(filename)
      .getMetadata();

    const metadatas = [
      {id: 0, name: `Date: ${metadata.updated.substring(0,10)}, Time: ${metadata.updated.substring(11,19)}`},
      {id: 1, name: metadata.contentType}
    ];

    res.json(metadatas);
  } catch (e) {
    next(e);
  }
});

const port = 5000;

app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`));
```

However, I do not know how to obtain this metadata information for clicked image. How can I obtain the metadata for clicked element?

Answer (score 0):

When you are displaying these images on React Frontend, there will be a `filename` associated with each image.
Now `onClick` of any Image send this `fileName` to backend API to fetch the metadata.

And in your `app.get("/api/metadata", cors(), async (req, res, next) => {`
you should extract your `fileName` from `req` request object, either as params or queryString, and use that `fileName` instead of the `const filename = "detected/0.jpg";`

Comment: As you said, I will try to do first post request from frontend to backend, then get request. I do not understand extracting "fileName" from "req" object. Could you explain what does extracting mean here?

Comment: the api to fetch metadata is a `get`. The handler code you shared for api has a reference to a `fileName`. Currently as per your code, this `filename` is a constant value.
To achieve the functionality of dynamically fetching metadata for clicked image, you should pass the filename as a request-param to your `get` request. And then read that param to get the requested filename.  To extract request params in express, you can see: https://stackabuse.com/get-query-strings-and-parameters-in-express-js/#:~:text=Your%20query%20parameters%20can%20be,retrieved%20parameters%20as%20this%20object.

Comment: I will look at the website you shared with me

Comment: My URL does not include any parameters like page, limit, etc. Does this effect my result? Because, the website you shared includes some parameters (page and limit) and the author can do this operation.